# Background of spriteKit exceeds the frame of the phone IOS

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, resolution, screen-size

I am having deep trouble understanding how the resolution on different devices work. so what I have done is made a background image 1024 x 768 then tested on an iphone 5 device. when i run it, the bottom half of the screen is chopped off so as the top. I did use AspectFill as my scale mode, but even when i test it on iphone 6 or 6+, the background is still chopped off.

the following is my code for gameviewcontroller

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit

    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true

    if GameSettings.Debugging.ALL_TellMeStatus {
      skView.showsFPS = GameSettings.Debugging.ALL_ShowFrameRate
      skView.showsNodeCount = GameSettings.Debugging.ALL_ShowNodeCount
      skView.showsDrawCount = GameSettings.Debugging.IOS_ShowDrawCount
      skView.showsQuadCount = GameSettings.Debugging.IOS_ShowQuadCount
      skView.showsPhysics = GameSettings.Debugging.IOS_ShowPhysics
      skView.showsFields = GameSettings.Debugging.IOS_ShowFields

    }


    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true



    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    _ = SGResolution(screenSize: view.bounds.size, canvasSize: scene.size)

    skView.presentScene(scene)

  }

      override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
      }

      override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Landscape
      }

      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
  }

      override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
      }
    }
```

and my code for adding the background image in.

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Artboard 1")
        background.posByCanvas(0.5, y: 0.5)
        background.xScale = 1.2
        background.yScale = 1.2
        background.size = self.frame.size
        background.zPosition = -1
        addChild(background)
```

is this the right way to start the screen size or should i start with an iPad screen size then descale it? If anyone can lead me on how to attack this problem that would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspect fill is going to chop off parts of your background.

Your scene has an aspect ratio of 4:3

Your device has an aspect ratio of 16:9

`AspectFill` will scale your scene in its current aspect ratio(4:3) till the farthest borders are filled,  allowing for the entire view to show the scene and have no black borders;

`AspectFit` will scale till the nearest borders are filled in, which will give you black bars to preserve the aspect ratio.

If you want the 4:3 to not be preserved, then you use `.Fill`,  this of course is going to make your sprites fatter on 16:9 because it will just stretch the scene till it hits all 4 borders

Finally you have `.ResizeFill`, and what this does is resizes the scene bounds to match your screen size, so if you start with a 1024x768 scene, it will turn it into a 736x414 scene when you view it on iPhone 6+ (This is because we are working in points, not pixels,  the pixel count would be x3 (so 2208x1242) which hardware will shrink to 1920x1080).

You need to take a step back and evaluate how you want your game to look on 3 different aspect ratios

16:9,3:2, and 4:3, and determine which of the 4 methods above works best for you.

Now in my opinion, I find that Aspect Fill works best, and I just plan for the 16:9 aspect ratio, making sure I do not put any important information in the areas that may be cropped for a game, but this does not work for everybody, and unfortunately nobody can help you with this part, since it is your game and you are the one that determines its look and feel.